# Can I save the collectively created level in Ultimate Chicken Horse? How?

Tags: ultimate-chicken-horse

In the game Ultimate Chicken Horse in Party mode you and your 3 additional local players create a hard to pass level. The level evolves with each round as each player puts new pieces into it and changes the level. At the end of the match or at any point mid-match the level is at its best. Is there any way to save this setup to play again later? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can save the current level you’re viewing at any time, then play or edit it later.

### Save a level mid-game

1. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the Pause menu.
2. Click Save and Share Level.
3. Click Locally for where you want to save it.
4. Click Challenge next to “Level Type”.
5. Click the Save a Local Copy button that appears.

   [image: Save and Share Level during a game in Ultimate Chicken Horse]

### Play that level later

1. In the Treehouse (the level select area), jump down the well and stand in front of the Level Loader computer.
2. Jump to open the Level Loader interface.
3. Click on the Local Levels tab.
4. Click the specific saved level you want to play to view its details. From here, you can load the level in various modes or manage the level data. (Free Play is the mode for editing levels freely.)

   [image: load previously saved level in Ultimate Chicken Horse]